# When implementing proactive messaging using the BotFramework how can i ensure bot state is not over written

Tags: botframework

In c#

When a message is received from a person typing, the bot controller fires _adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, _bot) Middleware saves the current bot state including the dialog stack once the turn completes.

When a proactive message is received a different controller fires which calls _adapter.ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback) Middleware again saves bot state including the dialog stack when the turn completes.

There seems to be a race condition. The bot server code can run concurrently for the same conversation and therefore the saved bot state + dialog stack ends up being last run wins.

1. A user message is received processing begins using _adapter.ProcessAsync The current bot state is captured
2. a proactive message is received processing begins using _adapter.ContinueConversationAsync The current bot state is captured.
   It interrupts the current dialog from step 1, and starts an adaptive dialog, asking a question, then saves it version of bot state
3. The user message _adapter.ProcessAsync completes step 1 above and  saves its version of bot state over the top of the proactive

When this happens, odd things appear on the bot, questions showing answers meant for other question or it can manifest as a bot framework can not find dialog id exception, as the expected dialog is not on the dialog stack when dialog is continued.

Is there a way of ensuring messages to the bot server code are processed sequentially for each conversationid / channel /

Comment: You should edit your question. It’s hard to read.